# CopyIntoItems - Upload a new version of file

Tags: web-services, versioning

I've uploaded files to a document library using the copy web service (copyintoitems). Is it possible to upload files which already exists in the library but upload it as a new version (versioning enabled for the library)?

Comment: Hi i am also having same requirement, Please help on this

Comment: See [Overwrite SharePoint document using CopyIntoItems service of Copy.asmx](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58512/1834)